# Want to write Update query in LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<long> data,long playlistid=0)
{
    var q = from client in my.Clients(0, 0)
            join m in db.Playlists on client.ClientId equals m.ClientId
            join meta in db.ContentMetaDatas on m.PlaylistId equals meta.PlaylistId
            select new{
                    m.PlaylistId,
                    meta.ContentId,
                    m.PlaylistShortDescription,
                    meta.ContentMetaDataImage,
                    m.PlaylistTitle
                };


    return Json(data);
}
```

This is my Controller code in mvc for Updating values through AJAX Post. How can the database be updated?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework should help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ only supports querying (SELECT) from a datasource - inserting, updating, deleting, cannot be done with LINQ *directly*. You can just loop trough all the clients, and update them - not as sexy as LINQ but should be easy and painless :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399339.aspx << example